# ITextsharp: Error reading a pdf file in Byte[] content (PdfReader)

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I'm trying to merge several PDFs into a single file through a list that contains their content in byte[].  When opening a document from the Byte[] list with PdfReader, the program launches the following exception: **"the document has no pages"**. When I review the contents of the Byte[] list there are complete, but the exception is always launched.

I try to download the content of that single page separately and the generated document launches error when opening it. The division of the pdf does well because it generates each document in physical and makes it perfect for each page of the PDF.

I appreciate your help or opinions in this situation.

This is the code I use to split and merge documents:

```
    public List<byte[]> SplitPDF(byte[] contentPdf)
    {
        try
        {
            var listBythe = new List<byte[]>();
            PdfImportedPage page = null;
            PdfCopy PdfCopy = null;
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(contentPdf);
            for (int numPage = 1; numPage <= reader.NumberOfPages; numPage++)
            {
                Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
                var mStream = new MemoryStream();
                PdfCopy = new PdfCopy(doc, mStream);
                doc.Open();
                page = PdfCopy.GetImportedPage(reader, numPage);
                PdfCopy.AddPage(page);
                listBythe.Add(mStream.ToArray());
                doc.Close();
            }

            MergePdfToPage(listBythe);
            return listBythe;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    private byte[] MergePdfToPage(List<byte[]>contentPage)
    {
        byte[] docPdfByte = null;
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        using (Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER))
        {
            PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(doc, ms);
            doc.Open();
            var num = doc.PageNumber;
            foreach (var file in contentPage.ToArray())
            {
                using (var reader = new PdfReader(file))
                {
                    copy.AddDocument(reader);
                }
            }
            doc.Close();
            docPdfByte = ms.ToArray();
        }
        return docPdfByte;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop you do

```
            Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
            var mStream = new MemoryStream();
            PdfCopy = new PdfCopy(doc, mStream);
            doc.Open();
            page = PdfCopy.GetImportedPage(reader, numPage);
            PdfCopy.AddPage(page);
            listBythe.Add(mStream.ToArray());
            doc.Close();
```

In particular you retrieve the `mStream` bytes *before* closing `doc`. But before `doc` is closed, the pdf is incomplete in  `mStream`!

To get a complete pdf from `mStream`, please change the order of instructions an do

```
            Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
            var mStream = new MemoryStream();
            PdfCopy = new PdfCopy(doc, mStream);
            doc.Open();
            page = PdfCopy.GetImportedPage(reader, numPage);
            PdfCopy.AddPage(page);
            doc.Close();
            listBythe.Add(mStream.ToArray());
```

instead.

Comment: That was indeed the problem. A little nonsense that I didn't realize.

Thank you mkl.

Answer (score 1):

I created something for you, hopefully it will work as well as it did for me.
Class :

```
public class PDFFactory
{
    public PDFFactory()
    {
        PdfDocument = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 65, 65, 60, 60);
    }

    private Document _pdfDocument;
    public Document PdfDocument
    {
        get
        {
            return _pdfDocument;
        }
        set
        {
            _pdfDocument = value;
        }
    }

    private MemoryStream _pdfMemoryStream;
    public MemoryStream PDFMemoryStream
    {
        get
        {
            return _pdfMemoryStream;
        }
        set
        {
            _pdfMemoryStream = value;
        }
    }

    private string _pdfBase64;
    public string PDFBase64
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.DocumentClosed)
                return _pdfBase64;
            else
                return null;
        }
        set
        {
            _pdfBase64 = value;
        }
    }

    private byte[] _pdfBytes;
    public byte[] PDFBytes
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.DocumentClosed)
                return _pdfBytes;
            else
                return null;
        }
        set
        {
            _pdfBytes = value;
        }
    }

    public byte[] GetPDFBytes()
    {
        PDFDocument.Close();
        return PDFMemoryStream.GetBuffer();
    }

    public void closeDocument()
    {
        PDFDocument.Close();
        PDFBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(this.PDFMemoryStream.GetBuffer());
        PDFBytes = this.PDFMemoryStream.GetBuffer();
    }
}
```

Service:

```
public byte[] ()
{
    PDFFactory pdf_1 = new PDFFactory();
    PDFFactory pdf_2 = new PDFFactory();
    List<byte[]> sourceFiles = new List<byte[]>();
    sourceFiles.Add(pdf_1.GetPDFBytes);
    sourceFiles.Add(pdf_2.GetPDFBytes);

    PDFFactory pdfFinal = new PDFFactory();
    for (int fileCounter = 0; fileCounter <= sourceFiles.Count - 1; fileCounter += 1)
    {
        PdfReader reader2 = new PdfReader(sourceFiles[fileCounter]);
        int numberOfPages = reader2.NumberOfPages;

        for (int currentPageIndex = 1; currentPageIndex <= numberOfPages; currentPageIndex++)
        {
            // Determine page size for the current page
            pdfFinal.PDFDocument.SetPageSize(reader2.GetPageSizeWithRotation(currentPageIndex));

            // Create page
            pdfFinal.PDFDocument.NewPage();
            PdfImportedPage importedPage = pdfFinal.PDFWriter.GetImportedPage(reader2, currentPageIndex);

            // Determine page orientation
            int pageOrientation = reader2.GetPageRotation(currentPageIndex);
            if ((pageOrientation == 90) || (pageOrientation == 270))
                pdfFinal.PDFWriter.DirectContent.AddTemplate(importedPage, 0, -1.0F, 1.0F, 0, 0, reader2.GetPageSizeWithRotation(currentPageIndex).Height);
            else
                pdfFinal.PDFWriter.DirectContent.AddTemplate(importedPage, 1.0F, 0, 0, 1.0F, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    pdfFinal.closeDocument();
    return pdfFinal.PDFBytes;
}
```

Let me know if it helped.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Nestor.  Your code has helped me a little to order mine, but the problem is when reading the contents of the file on this line:

" var reader = new PdfReader(file);"